# Change Color of Non-selected Bokeh Lines

Tags: python, bokeh

I am starting to use Bokeh to plot data that does not share a common x or y variable. I would like to be able to select a line and have the other, non-selected lines, grey out. Ideally the selected line would also be brought to the front of the plot.

So far I been able to get the line selected, but I can't find a way of "greying out" the non-selected lines, or setting the level of the selected line.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import Line,TapTool

output_file("test.html")

x0s = np.random.randint(0,20,20)
y0s = np.random.randint(0,20,20)
x1s = np.random.randint(0,20,20)
y1s = np.random.randint(0,20,20)

p_left = figure(tools=[TapTool()])

for xs,ys in zip([x0s,x1s],[y0s,y1s]):
    source = ColumnDataSource({'x': xs, 'y': ys})
    default_line = Line(x='x', y='y', line_color='blue', line_width=2)
    selected_line = Line(line_color='red', line_width=4)
    nonselected_line = Line(line_color='grey')
    p_left.add_glyph(source,default_line,selection_glyph=selected_line,nonselection_glyph=nonselected_line)

show(p_left)
```

Comment: The logic issue here, I believe, is that when you plot things individually, they are *not recognized as part of any collection* of things that could be non-selected.  In the dox, they create a group of circles with one command, and then it makes sense that some are selected/not-selected.  I'm not sure if you can make singletons (which is what you are making) can be put in a non-select state.  I think the only way to have lines that are non-selected is to use `multi_line` which creates a collection of lines.  If someone else has a solution to make individual items non-selected, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a similar situation, and found this example:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#selected-and-unselected-glyphs

Haven't tried it out myself, but seems to be close to what you're looking for.

**EDIT** Just tried it, worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: Could you show some scripts please? I'm trying the same thing, but it always has all lines selected or all non-selected -- I can't select one line out of 3